# How can I remove the possibility of SQL Injection while appending the binds a user submits in a API against Snowflake?

Tags: javascript, node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The end goal of my code is to query the database using the query variable with the binds submitted by the user.

It would be very helpful for logging to be able to see the actual values that were passed in. I tried to accomplish this by appending these binds as a comment, but I realize now that this opens us up to SQL Injection. Is there any way to solve for this or is this something that will just need to be removed?

Nodejs backend and the DB is Snowflake.

```js
const database = require('../services/database.js');
async function find(context) {
const clientdetails = {
  clientid: context.clientid,
};
  let query = `SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE WHERE V_ID = :1 /* V_ID */`
  
console.log(query);
const binds = {
  V_ID: context.id
};
let bindarray = [];
for (const x in binds) {
  bindarray.push(binds[x])
}
try {
  query = query + `
  /* BINDARRAY: ` + JSON.stringify(binds) + `*/`
  const result = await database.dbExecute(query, bindarray, clientdetails, 1);
  return result;
} catch (err) {
  return err
}}
module.exports.find = find;
```

Comment: Escape the inserted string. Ensure there is no `*/` "comment close" in it and you are good to go.  That effectively only prevents SQL Injection regarding the included comment. When building some sort of "dynamic" queries u anyways have a high risk of SQL injection in general.   Since it is only for logging purposes, you may also create a log table holding the query and the given comment as content. OFC, always escaped ..

Comment: If you use the log table, there's no need to escape anything. Just insert into it using parameter binding and that takes care of escaping.